# Unable to bind TCP incoming server socket to 80 (Address already in use: bind)

Tags: tcp, port80, vuze

OS: **Windows 10**
Application being used: **Vuze**

Enabled incoming port number to "**80**" to support HTTP seeding.

Since setting up **Zookeeper** and **Apache Kafka**. I receive this 'bind' error.

[Error script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfI4O.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeBdk.png)

I have checked PIDs on Task Manager and run the following proc on Powershell:

```html
$proc = @{};
Get-Process | ForEach-Object { $proc.Add($_.Id, $_) };
netstat -aon | Select-String "\s*([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+):([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+):([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)?\s+([^\s]+)" | ForEach-Object {
    $g = $_.Matches[0].Groups;
    New-Object PSObject |
        Add-Member @{ Protocol =           $g[1].Value  } -PassThru |
        Add-Member @{ LocalAddress =       $g[2].Value  } -PassThru |
        Add-Member @{ LocalPort =     [int]$g[3].Value  } -PassThru |
        Add-Member @{ RemoteAddress =      $g[4].Value  } -PassThru |
        Add-Member @{ RemotePort =         $g[5].Value  } -PassThru |
        Add-Member @{ State =              $g[6].Value  } -PassThru |
        Add-Member @{ PID =           [int]$g[7].Value  } -PassThru |
        Add-Member @{ Process = $proc[[int]$g[7].Value] } -PassThru;
#} | Format-Table Protocol,LocalAddress,LocalPort,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,State -GroupBy @{Name='Process';Expression={$p=$_.Process;@{$True=$p.ProcessName; $False=$p.MainModule.FileName}[$p.MainModule -eq $Null] + ' PID: ' + $p.Id}} -AutoSize
} | Sort-Object PID | Out-GridView
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm not an expert on ports.

1. Should I be expecting the PID for Vuze to be "**ESTABLISHED**" or "**LISTENING**" on the Powershell output grid?
2. Is there a way to prioritise Port 80 for Vuze? PID 0 / PID 4 (system) are shown. Is there any quick fix for this... asides from re-installing the OS?

Comment: Kafka nor Zookeeper use port 80, by default. You have a separate problem

Comment: 1) ports don't have priority. 2) netstat shows processes on Unix, I don't know about windows 3) These errors shouldn't stop you from running something on port 80 with Kafka or Zookeeper on their default ports

Comment: Thanks for your input, both. Much appreciated! I think it may be an issue with Java (either a particular setting or how it was installed).

Comment: Java also doesn't start any TCP servers on port 80, by default